# can't add user to %2% group when installing oracle 19c on windows 8.1

Tags: oracle, windows-8.1

This is most likely repost of the same question, but I could not find the answer and I cant fix this error. I tried to install different versions, same result. if any kind of additional information is needed please tell me to provide it. I also checked answer on similar question where they said to create user group from compmgmt.msc, tried that and still no result.

[image]

Comment: `%2%` is almost certainly a `.cmd` file notation for the 2nd argument passed on a command line. It looks like `%2%` is empty. Are you sure you're calling the install script with all the required arguments? That is the place to look. I don't see how we can help in this situation, you'll need to put on your thinking cap to figure out how that is happening. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after two years, when i needed to install it again, and faced the same problem, I solved it by changing the computer name. username and computer name arent supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a moment ago I had the same error you mentioned but in Windows 10, however, looking closely at the image you attach and the action that is running at that time in the "progress", is not the same as I had, ie, the registry key was not being updated, but that window `Failed to add user \ user install user to %2% group` came up when I was in a different process that I do not remember exactly what it was.

**Once explained that, the solution I found for my case, was to "change the system user name" by the original user name, this through "`netplwiz`" and the installation continued correctly.**

What happens is that at the time of installing the operating system asks us for a user name, whose name over time I changed it.  What happens is that when we make that change of user name, in fact the change is only superficial apparently and does not change it completely from the root.

Sorry for all the padding, however, maybe this will help someone who has the same error.

Note: The installer that is inside the compressed: "`WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home.zip`" that is downloaded from the official page of oracle I unzipped it in "`C:\Users\USERNAME\App\App_db_home`" where "`app`" is a folder that I created on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the system name
Select Start  > Settings  > System > About.

Select Rename this PC.

Enter a new name and select Next. You may be asked to sign in.

Select Restart now or Restart later.